# Is there a way to reverse changes done to a txt file in Documents by Readdle?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, file, files.app

I wanted to open a txt file on my iPhone/iOS. When I clicked the file in iOS file app, it opened up in Documents app automatically. I then before I knew it managed to overwrite some codes/passwords I had saved in the txt file. Stuff I cannot remember. I then closed the documents app and thought no harm done, as I can just open the txt file and repeat the previous procedure. But when I clicked to open it, and it automatically opened up in documents app, the changes were still there, as it apparently saved all changes done. And now I can't seem to find any option to reverse and open up the original version of the txt file, before I accidentally changed a few passwords.

I mean, open up a document and writing something, and no option to go back to original, nor any option to make changes reverse. Kinda stupid. The app apparently saves any changes done and that's it. But there got to be a way to reverse the action somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, file management applications have the ability to handle any type of file.

From the iCloud drive, for instance, you can make it open the specific **file** in a specific application by **holding** your finger on the file icon you desire to open. You then select and by selecting the **"More..."** option from the menu that will hopefully appear, and then selecting **"Share Item... "** and finally selecting an application from the list.

Reversing the actions might be undone by simply opening back to the default application it was made to be opened with.

A similar question was answered here, you might need a specific application to handle **text** files.

Reference:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7652455